# Calling a function return Promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I was trying to implement Promises when I get error saying

```
TypeError: productService.getSwapItems is not a function
```

I have created a DB class as

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

class Database {
    constructor( config ) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    }

    query(sql, args) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.query(sql, args, (error, result) => {
                if(error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }

    close() {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve();
            })
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

And then a service class

```
let Database = require('./mysql.db');

const database = new Database({
    host: "db-host",
    user: "username",
    password: "password",
    database: "databasename"
});

class ProductService {
    getSwapItems(item_ids_array) {
        this.queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE from_item_id IN (" + item_ids_array + ")";
        return database.query(this.queryStr, null); // database.query returns a promise, so getSwapItems() will also return promise??
    }
}

module.exports = ProductService;
```

When productService using code below, I get error.

```
var item_ids_array = <Array Values>;
productService.getSwapItems(item_ids_array)
.then( rows => {
    console.log(rows);
}).catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Error is

```
productService.getSwapItems(item_ids_array)
  TypeError: productService.getSwapItems is not a function
```

Comment: How is `productService` initialized?

Comment: This isn't a problem with the promise it's supposed to return. Are you sure `productService` is an **instance** of `ProductService`?

Comment: Ahh that's the problem ... 
I thought 
'const productService = require('../db/product.service');' will initialize product service. But I think it;s similar to java import and we have to explicitly create productService like 'const productService = new ProductService();' Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module exports a *class* ProductService with regular method `getSwapItems`. Classes are first-class citizens in JS, so you can assign them (as value) to any variable any way you like - including `require`-ing a module.

```
const ProductService = require('./db/product.service');
```

But the class is like a recipe for creating an instance of the class you can use, not an instance of the class itself.  To actually create an instance of the class, use the `new` keyword:

```
const productService = new ProductService();
```

Only after that you'll be able to use methods of this class the usual way.

Comment: "But class is not an object".  You should probably fix up that wording a bit.  I think I know what you meant, but you could clear up the words.  A class is an object all by itself - it's just not an instance of the class.  You have to call the constructor with new to create an instance of the class that you can then call normal methods on.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right, of course - any reference value is an object in JS, and classes (which are essentially functions) are certainly not exceptions. Not sure how to phrase this better, though.

Comment: I proposed some edits to improve the wording.